# How can I create an azure customMetric alert for an alert that has never fired?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I have some error alerts in a prod env that I would like to be alerted for if they fire. The issue is that they have never fired so I cannot see them in the portal.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you not trust an alert being fired or do you want to validate that the action defined for the alert was properly configured? If you do not trust an alert being fired you don't trust azure monitor, that is an issue you cannot solve with an additional alert :-) If you expected an alert being fired but it didn't you would be better of checking the definition of the alert.

Comment: Basically I have a success and failure try/catch. I want to send an alert when the failure one occurs, but since it hasn't happened before, I can't select it to create the alert.

Comment: @HahnSolo, in your catch block, you can send a custom error message like "an error occurs" to application insights -> error table, then you can easily create an alert based on that error message.

Comment: @HahnSolo alerts are not entities you can send. In application insights you can define a query, for example show me the number of exception of a given type with a given message in the past 5 minutes. Then you define an alert that is fired when a given condition is met, like: the result of the example query > 0. So, you can create alerts before the conditions are met. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I now better understand your issue. Today I was notified using [this post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/improvements-to-azure-monitor-metric-alerts/) of a new capability:

> **Define an alert rule on a custom metric that isn't emitted yet**
>
> When creating a metric alert rule, the metric name is validated against the Metric Definitions API to make sure it exists. In some cases, you'd like to create an alert rule on a custom metric even before it’s emitted. For example, when creating (using an Resource Manager template) an Application Insights resource that will emit a custom metric, along with an alert rule that monitors that metric.
>
> To avoid having the deployment fail when trying to validate the custom metric’s definitions, you can use the skipMetricValidation parameter in the criteria section of the alert rule, which will cause the metric validation to be skipped.
> ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-troubleshoot-metric#define-an-alert-rule-on-a-custom-metric-that-isnt-emitted-yet))

Comment: This is it chief!

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a try/catch, then you can consider sending a custom error message to application insights(the logic here is that since you know the custom error message, you can use this pre-defined message to create an alert), by using the code below in your catch block:

```
        try
        {
           //your code            
        }
        catch
        {
            //if you're using ILogger which is integrated with application insights.
            _logger.LogError(new Exception(),"custom error: xxxx");
                           
            //your other code
        }
```

Then nav to azure portal -> the application insights -> Logs:

1.Write the query like below:

```
exceptions  
| where customDimensions.FormattedMessage == "custom error: xxxx"
```

2.Select the query, and click the run button.

3.At last, click the "New alert rule" button to create the alert.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how can I send that alert to app insights in the first place? This is a prod env so I can't just run stuff like that if you know what I mean.

Comment: @HahnSolo, what do you mean that "how can I send that alert to app insights in the first place"?

Comment: @HahnSolo, not sure if I understand you correctly. If you don't want to send custom errors to application insights, then you can do things like below: if any error occurs, the error will be logged into application insights, then you can just write query(the query should be very simple, like `exceptions`) to check if there are any results in the exceptions table -> then create an alert.